# Adding a subform to a form in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the most convenient way to create a subform with a list in another WordPress form? I am creating a plugin with a newsletter kinda function. So, I need to select recipients from a list. I have already made a custom form, but need to add the subform.

I'm adding an image below to illustrate what I want: [image]

Comment: Any attempts on this? Maybe you can go with an ajax based solution, or, use input buttons and check if they are set when you process the request on the page?

Comment: I have the main form ready, but not really sure where I should go now. I was also thinking about maybe using an "add recipents"-link/button, and then get some sort of popup, where I get the list to choose from. And when they are chosen there will be some stats (ie. "50/150 selected") by the link/button in the main form.

Comment: I still don't get what you really want. From my understanding, you should create the list and, when you select somebody, handle the event with jQuery and add it to a list/array which you process afterwards when submitting. That's what I'd do. If you want a server only approach, you should create inside the form, a submit button and, with php check if the button was clicked with `isset($_POST['button_name'])`. Try to show some code or something so others can understand what you want.

Comment: I went for a server side approach (designed like the illustration in the first post). Doesn't have a solution yet though, but your post made me think it through. The subform underneath the main form might be looking a bit complexed when the list is getting really big, so I'll see if I'll make a javascript-popup for the list later just to make it look tidier.

Comment: If you have a big list of names, it could be a big user interface improv if you break down the list by the first letter of the name. You can do so jQuery to achieve this. Glad I could help :)